# Common practices in Android Firebase: How to store data relative to signed users?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm working on an Android app in which users can sign up and log in. If they are logged in, they can indicate some information about them, and choose an avatar.

Both textual data and avatars are stored in Firebase.

We assume that textual data contains some personal information. That's not the case for avatars (at least, we assume it isn't).

**My questions are:** how could I store these both informations in Firebase, in order to associate them to the correct user? Is there any best practice guide about this subject? Should I store the UID of the users as the key of these both fields, in Firebase?

## About the users

A little precision. Users of my app are not Firebase users. They are people which have downloaded my app, signed-up and signed-in, as you do with all the apps you download on the Playstore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's conventional to use the UID of the user from Firebase Authentication to store per-user information.

Comment: I think you're talking about OAuth2 Authentication (with Firebase). However, it'd mean users have a firebase account and/or my app communicates with a server that I'd own to handle the OAuth2 authentication. But such a server doesn't exist, and users of my app don't have a Firebase account (they just have an Android / Facebook / ... acount). Users of my app aren't computer scientists - I edited the OP

Comment: Then you'll have to come up with your own way of uniquely identifying users, represented as a string, and use that value.  I'm not assuming that users somehow bring their own ID - that would be kind of silly actually.  You need to come up with that ID.

Comment: There isn't any common practice, generic method to do that? I mean, a lot of apps provide sign-up and sign-in features, and handle storage of data associated to users. And most of these apps don't force their users to create a Firebase account. Take this example: Tinder allows users to log in with Facebook and Google accounts, between others. But it doesn't propose Firebase connection. By the way, 99% of people don't even know what is Firebase.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding what the requirement is here.  You don't make the users sign up for a Firebase account, you use Firebase Authentication in your app to have them sign into your app using one of their existing accounts (Google, Facebook, GitHub, etc).  Firebase Auth will give you back a UID for that user.  They never have to know about it or see it.  If you don't use Firebase Auth to get a UID like this, you provide your own UID.

Comment: Thank you! So now I use Google Sign-in API, which allows me to get this UID for the signed-in user. All the data and GUI of my application that are only visible by a signed-in user and that are relative to this signed-in user is stored under the key which is this UID, in the Firebase Firestore db.